# Deriving the set generated by two permutations

Tags: group-theory

It's easy to find out the set generated by a single permutation since we can deduce the order of the permutation.

But i find it hard to do so for set generated by more than one element.

What is the best method to find out all the elements of <(1,2,3,4),(1,2)(3,4)> ?

Comment: Your example is the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: im referring to the permutation group here. (1,2,3,4) and (1,2)(3,4) are cyclic permutation.

Comment: can you help me with this question?

is there a method to approach such question?

if i were to just try to list all out the possible permutations generated by (1,2,3,4),(1,2)(3,4) , there's a high possibility that i will miss out some permutations.

Comment: As I said, the two permutations are easily seen to generate the dihedral group of order $8$ i.e. the symmetry group of a square.  There is a general  algorithm know as the Schreier-Sims algorithm, which you could do a search for.

Comment: It is sometimes (mostly) superfluous to generate all the elements of a group, it suffices to have some basic elements that permits to determine diverse properties of the group, see the [Schreier-Sims algorithm](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Graduiertenkolleg/schools/2011/slides/slides_ss11_niemeyer_2.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the intent of doing the exercise

> What familiar group is generated by $\langle(1\,2\,3\,4),(1\,2)(3\,4)\rangle < S_4$?

is not to devise a general way to describe a group from generators and relations, but to just *notice* what group it is. In this case, it is the dihedral group $D_4$: the group of symmetries of the square. You should see this because $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ is *one rotation* of the symmetric group (like rotating a square), and $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ can be viewed as *flipping* the symmetric group about it's middle (like flipping a square).

And then you should realize that the general dihedral group $D_n$ looks like

$$
\langle(1\,2\,3\dotsc n)\,,(1\;n)(2\;n\!\!-\!\!1)\dotsb(\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor\;n/2)\rangle < S_n
$$